# How to convert rows to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| toyota | yellow |
| nissan | blue |
| toyota | red |
| nissan | black |

I want to convert the table to this:

| toyota | nissan |
| --- | --- |
| yellow | blue |
| red | black |

How can I do this?

I tried using this command:

```
SELECT * (CASE Name WHEN 'toyota' THEN Value END) toyota,
         (CASE Name WHEN 'nissan' THEN Value END) nissan
FROM testTable
```

But that results in a table like this:

| toyota | nissan |
| --- | --- |
| yellow | NULL |
| NULL | blue |
| red | NULL |
| NULL | black |

Help? Thanks

Comment: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Let me ask a question and hopefully it will illustrate why it isn't doing what you expected.

You want

```
toyota    nissan
----------------
yellow    blue
red       black
```

but equally you could have

```
toyota    nissan
----------------
yellow    black
red       blue
```

How does the database decide that yellow and blue go in the same line? There is nothing in the original table to tie the two rows together.

The database doesn't know which of black or blue to associate yellow with, so it doesn't associate it with either.

Comment: I'd like it so that each value under 'toyota' and 'nissan' columns is listed in the order that was shown in original table. Since yellow is shown first, then red shown second for 'toyota' in original table, that's how I want it in the new table. Same for nissan. Is this possible?

Comment: @user2689893 There is no such thing as a natural order on tables, so " the order that was shown in original table" doesn't exists. It can be that order this time, but there is no guarantee that it won't change on another query. If you want an order, you need to specify it explicitely

Answer (score 2):

Using a full outer join

```
select toyota, nissan from 
(select value toyota, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by value desc) r 
      from testtable 
      where name = 'toyota') t
    full outer join
(select value nissan, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by value desc) r 
      from testtable 
      where name = 'nissan') n
    on t.r =n.r
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pivot` is possible also:

```
declare @table table (Name varchar(50), Value varchar(50))
insert into @table values ('toyota', 'yellow'), ('nissan', 'blue'),
    ('toyota', 'red'), ('nissan', 'black')

;with t as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Name order by Value)
    from @table
)
select Toyota, Nissan
from t
    pivot (max(Value) for Name in ([Toyota],[Nissan])) p
```

Comment: Works great, but I'm finding that it splits the rows back out if I add another row (e.g. toyota, green). Depends on what user2689893 wants to do.