# grouping and switching the columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2012

I don't know if this would officially be called a pivot, but the result that I would like is this:

```
+------+---------+------+
| Alex | Charley | Liza |
+------+---------+------+
|  213 |     345 |    1 |
|   23 |     111 |    5 |
|   42 |      52 |    2 |
|  323 |         |    5 |
|   23 |         |    1 |
|  324 |         |    5 |
+------+---------+------+
```

my input data is in this form:

```
+-----+---------+
| Apt |  Name   |
+-----+---------+
| 213 | Alex    |
|  23 | Alex    |
|  42 | Alex    |
| 323 | Alex    |
|  23 | Alex    |
| 324 | Alex    |
| 345 | Charley |
| 111 | Charley |
|  52 | Charley |
|   1 | Liza    |
|   5 | Liza    |
|   2 | Liza    |
|   5 | Liza    |
|   1 | Liza    |
|   5 | Liza    |
+-----+---------+
```

because I have approximately 100 names, I don't want to have to do a ton of sub queries lik this

```
select null, null, thirdcolumn from...
select null, seconcolumn from...
select firstcolumn from...
```

Is there a way to do this with `PIVOT` or otherwise?

Comment: There is a similar question ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276913/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns)), though for 100 names, probably dynamic query is your firend.

Comment: thanks! i would love to see a dynamic sql solution to this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic `PIVOT` and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(1000),
        @query  AS VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +   QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name
                          FROM #test
                          )sub
                    ORDER BY Name
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'')
PRINT @cols

SET @query = '
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT *
             FROM  #test)
    ,cte2 AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Apt)RowRank
             FROM  cte)
SELECT * 
FROM  cte2 
PIVOT (max(Apt) for Name in ('+@cols+')) p
            '
EXEC (@query)
```

[SQL Fiddle - Distinct List, Specific Order](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82af1/4/0)

Edit:  If you don't want the list to be distinct, eliminate the first cte above, and if you want to keep arbitrary ordering change the `ORDER BY` to `(SELECT 1)`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(1000),
        @query  AS VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +   QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name
                          FROM #test
                          )sub
                          ORDER BY Name
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'')
PRINT @cols

SET @query = '
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT 1))RowRank
             FROM  #test)
SELECT * 
FROM  cte 
PIVOT (max(Apt) for Name in ('+@cols+')) p
            '
EXEC (@query)
```

[SQL Fiddle - Full List, Arbitrary Order](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82af1/9/0)

And finally, if you didn't want the `RowRank` field in your results, just re-use the `@cols` variable in your `SELECT`:

```
SET @query = '
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT 1))RowRank
             FROM  #test)
SELECT '+@cols+' 
FROM  cte 
PIVOT (max(Apt) for Name in ('+@cols+')) p
            '
EXEC (@query)
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, this is something of a pain, but you can do it with SQL.  You are trying to concatenate the columns.

```
select seqnum,
       max(case when name = 'Alex' then apt end) as Alex,
       max(case when name = 'Charley' then apt end) as Charley,
       max(case when name = 'Liza' then apt end) as Liza
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

As a note:  there is no guarantee that the original ordering will be the same within each column.  As you know, SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you would need a column to specify the ordering.

To handle multiple names, I'd just get the list using a query such as:

```
select distinct 'max(case when name = '''+name+''' then apt end) as '+name+','
from t;
```

And copy the results into the query.